# Cardinality of set well defined

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Bit confused on this proof:

[image]

I thought we needed to create a bijection from $\{{1,..,m-1}\}$ to $\{1,...,n\}$.  So how does this proof work exactly?

Comment: Which book is this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim proven by induction, as a function of $m$, is that *no* suitable $n>m$ exists. We assume a minimal counterexample, i.e. a minimal $m$ for which *some* suitable $n>m$ exists. Let's call it $n_m$. But we show that for any such $m$ we can do the same thing with $m-1$ too. In other words, *some* suitable $n>m-1$ exists, albeit this time it's a different value of $n$ (in fact, $n_{m-1}=n_m-1$).

Comment: Quick aside: how does this kind of proof relate to induction exactly?  It logically the same as 'mathematical induction'?

Comment: Proving that from one counterexample you can always generate a smaller counterexample, so the set of counterexamples can't have a smallest element and therefore must be empty, is the contrapositive form of a proof by more traditional forms of induction.

Comment: @hellos321 [Yes](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Well-Ordering_Principle_and_Induction).